# How to clear cin on console?

Tags: c++, cin

So I have created a sort of Bomberman and when I ask for the player's name to store the ranking, the console prints out the previous inputs (like WASD).

I tried to clear and ignore the cin but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Clearing the terminal is terminal specific.

Comment: Educated Guess: You've mixed your IO methods to get instant notification of key presses, and still get c++ streaming IO. Don't do this. Pick one input method and stick to it.

Comment: Please attach your code with the post for further visualization of whatever you're talking about.